What is this usage of には (NSfW language usage warning)

The character gets called a やりちん because he has many girls. So he says I'm not that! And then he adds this. Is he saying he has a compatibility with a specific person?  Or is it akin "You need compatibility with people?"

He is saying that "Everybody has their own compatibility." It carries the extra nuance that finding a compatible girl is a rare opportunity and anyone would act similarly in the same situation.
How do I interpret the sentence? The key point is that his sentence starts with "人"(people) and not "おれ"(I). So, he is not just talking about himself; he is referring to people in general. From the first character of his reply, he is preparing to justify that his behavior is similar to what most people would do.
Note that in Japanese culture, people tend to feel that behavior is not too bad if it's the same others'. So this type of justification is quite common in Japan.
